# Execute different tasks as different users in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, continuous-deployment, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible task that creates new users on a remote box, makes that user a `sudo` user, then disables the `root` user's SSH login. Subsequently all the tasks on the remote box(es) are run as this new user. Is there a method to switch to the new user in the same play/playbook?

For instance, this is the what the current directory structure looks like:

```
|-- initial_setup
|   |-- change_hostname.yml
|   |-- main.yml
|   `-- newuser.yml
|-- main.yml
|-- README.md
|-- roles
|   `-- apache
|       |-- conf
|       |   `-- httpd.conf
|       |-- handlers
|       |   `-- main.yml
|       `-- tasks
|           `-- main.yml
|          
`-- start_install.sh
```

At the moment, I run the **`start_install.sh`** script to begin proceedings:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install a new remote user with 'sudo' privileges
ansible-playbook initial_setup/main.yml

# Start main installation process
ansible-playbook main.yml
```

As shown above, it first executes `initial_setup/main.yml` and then proceeds to the "proper" playbook. Both of these are listed below:

**`initial_setup/main.yml`**

```
[root@testserver record1]# cat initial_setup/main.yml 
- include: newuser.yml
- include: change_hostname.yml
```

**`initial_setup/newuser.yml`**

```
---
- hosts: redbox1
  remote_user: root

  vars: 
    NEW_SUDO_USER: 'ansibleuser'

  tasks:
    - name: Create a new secondary, non-root, sudo user
      user: name={{ NEW_SUDO_USER }}
            password='testpass'
            shell='/bin/bash'
  # followed by the tasks to give the user sudo privileges, 
  # allow SSH access to the new user, remove root SSH etc.
```

and then the playbook proper (**`./main.yml`**) begins, like so:

```
[root@testserver record1]# cat main.yml 
---
- hosts: redbox1
  remote_user: ansibleuser
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  roles:
    - apache
```

I'm not sure that this is the proper way to get these tasks in done in Ansible (that is, using a shell script to execute different *plays*, each of which makes use of a different `remote_user`). Is there another, cleaner solution to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

> become_user set to user with desired privileges — the user you
>   ‘become’, NOT the user you login as. Does NOT imply become: yes, to
>   allow it to be set at host level

```
- name: Run a command as nobody
  command: somecommand
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: nobody
  become_flags: '-s /bin/sh'
.
```

Just a small example, you can create `variable` file, put it in your group variables inventory group_vars/all, playbook group_vars/all, inventory group_vars/* , playbook group_vars/* or in your role playbook and then include it from there, separate your new user creation to a different role, and then do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: redbox1
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  pre_tasks:

      - include_vars: "../environments/{{ env_name }}/group_vars/all"
      # or just put the var file in role and include it from the `new user` playbook, or you can do it from here.

      roles:
        - { role: 'newuser', tags: 'newuser', gather_facts: True, become: yes, become_user: root, become_method: sudo }
        - { role: 'apache', tags: 'apache', gather_facts: True, become: yes, become_user: ansibleuser, become_method: sudo }
```

the first role you run it as root user and the second one as ansible user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though this is not exactly the problem I was after, this gave me the idea....